# List with inadequate structure in the output of a defined function

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I've been dealing with some data that show quite a few outliers, so I decided to apply this method Wikipedia calls "Winsorizing" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsorizing).

I have several sets of data, which are organized in a 2D list, so that each line corresponds to one set of data.

I defined the winsorization function in a way that it acts on a single list of numbers. Because of that, when I apply this function to my data list, I am supposed to use a mapping function.

My problem arrives when I try to transpose the winsorized data to calculate its mean. Mathematica appears to be trying to map "Transpose" across the winsorized data although I didn't ask it to. This obviously leads to an error in the transposition because you can't transpose 1D lists. See the code below.

```
data = {{17682, 17890, 17648, 17595, 17654, 17603, 17654, 17638, 
17601, 17853, 17867, 17706, 17839, 17753, 17619, 4539783, 17477, 
17403, 17422, 17469}, {24650, 6250273, 24631, 24384, 24412, 24440,
 24865, 24427, 24651, 24625, 24418, 24415, 24556, 24415, 24396, 
24524, 24271, 24630, 24641, 24596}};

winsorize[list_, infQuantile_, supQuantile_] := 
  Module[{quantiles, list1},

   quantiles = {Quantile[#, infQuantile], Quantile[#, supQuantile]} &@list;

   list1 = If[# < quantiles[[1]], quantiles[[1]], #] & /@ list;

   If[# > quantiles[[2]], quantiles[[2]], #] & /@ list1
   ];

Mean[#] & @Transpose@winsorize[#, .1, .9] & /@ data
```

It gives this as a result

```
{Mean[Transpose[{17682, 17867, 17648, 17595, 17654, 17603, 17654, 17638, 
17601, 17853, 17867, 17706, 17839, 17753, 17619, 17867, 17477, 17422, 17422, 
17469}]], Mean[Transpose[{24650, 24651, 24631, 24384, 24412, 24440, 24651, 24427, 
24651, 24625, 24418, 24415, 24556, 24415, 24396, 24524, 24384, 24630, 24641, 
24596}]]}
```

together with an error message.

If I ask directly for the dimensions of the winsorized list,

```
Dimensions@winsorize[#, .1, .9] & /@ data
```

I get {{20}, {20}}, which makes no sense, since I understand it should give me {2, 20}. So it appears to me there's something weird happening to the list. But the funny thing is if I give it a name and then call it, it works nicely.

```
list = winsorize[#, .1, .9] & /@ data;
Dimensions@list
N@Mean[#] &@Transpose@list
```

giving

```
{2, 20}
{17661.8, 24524.9}
```

So, is this so kind of a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: I think you want `Mean@Transpose@(winsorize[#, .1, .9] & /@ data)`. Note the `()` to indicate the order of precedence of the operations. `@` has higher priority than `/@`, so it ends up being applied first, rather than after the mapping as you, I think, would want. Equivalently, you could write `winsorize[#, .1, .9] & /@ data // Transpose // Mean`.

Comment: Note also that your function practically already exists in *Mathematica*, and it's called [`Clip`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clip.html): `Clip[list, Quantile[list, {infQuantile, supQuantile}]]` will return the same as your `winsorize[list, infQuantile, supQuantile`.

Comment: I see. I didn't remember to check the precedences, but that makes perfect sense. Thank you!
Thanks also for pointing out that the Clip function could be used for this purpose.

Comment: Note that version 11.1 now has `WinsorizedMean[]` and `WinsorizedVariance[]` as built-in functions.

Comment: Good to know that. I haven't updated to version 11 yet.