# Winsorizing in Mathematica and the R package DescTools yields differing results

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I am currently trying to winsorize several datasets up to 1000 datapoints in R and in *Mathematica* for using those in regression estimations afterwards. Following the suggestion in the question http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/152936/list-with-inadequate-structure-in-the-output-of-a-defined-function, I used

```
Clip[grate16, Quantile[grate16, {.05, .95}]]
```

to winsorize my data in *Mathematica*. Yet, if I use the `Winsorize` function from the package ['DescTools'](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DescTools/index.html) in R with the code

```
Winsorize(grate16, probs = c(0.05, 0.95))
```

for exactly the same datasets, the results differ for some observations from about the 3 decimal-digit level which leads to heavily differing end results. Cursory documentation for this function can be found [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DescTools/versions/0.99.19/topics/Winsorize). The code (in GitHub) for this function can be found [here](https://github.com/cran/DescTools/blob/master/R/DescTools.r).

Since the deviations are so large for the same datasets, I do not think this is a numerical accuracy issue. I tried differing levels of precision and accuracy in *Mathematica* which, however, did not improve the situation. What am I missing?

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: I have very little experience with *R*; I think that discrepancies are due to the implicit method used in *R*'s quantile function; perhaps taking a look at how [`WinsorizedMean`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WinsorizedMean.html?q=WinsorizedMean) works, you can infer which method better suits your data and needs

Comment: Both *Mathematica* and *R* list the same 9 methods for estimating quantiles (`Quantile` in *Mathematica* and `quantile` in *R*).  The default methods just happen to be different.  So you just need to set the desired method in both to get the same results.

Comment: Can you post your `grate16` somewhere, so that potential answerers can experiment with it?

Comment: @JimB Looking at the code [here](https://github.com/cran/DescTools/blob/master/R/DescTools.r)  `Winsorize`  does not use `Quantile` by the `DescTools` but `quantile` by `base`.

Comment: @AntonAntonov Good observation.  I see from the link you provided that `quantile` is called by `Winsorize` without specifying one the 9 types so the default (`type=7` in *R*) is used.  This is the "mode-based estimate" in *Mathematica*.  So to match what *R* does the following should be used:  `Clip[grate16, Quantile[grate16, {.05, .95}, {{1, -1}, {0, 1}}]]`.

Comment: @JimB Could I prevail upon you to transform your comment into an answer? It is very valuable information which should be preserved; additionally the question would then show up as answered, making it more useful for further searches. I would do it myself, but I am not familiar enough with the topic.