# Statistical Error in the `TrimmedMean[...]`

Tags: functions, probability-or-statistics

Does anyone know if there is a native way of getting the error in the `TrimmedMean[]`? I also can't seem to find a standard error in the mean function for `Mean[]` (of course it's easy to make your own in this case).

Cheers

Comment: You should point ou in the title that it's about a _statistical_ error and not about an error message of the routine (which is usually a user problem). Most people here will find the statistical problem considerably more interesting!

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks for the tip! I will edit accordingly!

Comment: I am not aware of a “native way” but one can use the definition in the [`TrimmedMean`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrimmedMean.html) function page.

Comment: The estimation of a measure of precision (which is what I assume you mean by "error") for any particular statistic depends on how the data was sampled.  Are you only considering the situation where there is a simple random sample from a finite or infinite population?  Such details matter.  You might be better off asking the question about "what" estimates are available on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ and then ask "how to implement" here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a simple random sample from an infinite population (such as a random sample from a continuous probability distribution), then one can estimate the standard error of the trimmed mean in the following manner:

```
(* Generate a random sample *)
SeedRandom[12345];
x = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[10], 100];

(* Set trimming proportions in the lower and upper tails *)
αLower = 0.025;
αUpper = 0.025;

(* Trimmed mean *)
tm = TrimmedMean[x, {αLower, αUpper}]
(* 0.0919652 *)

(* Standard error of trimmed mean *)
seTM = WinsorizedVariance[x, {αLower, αUpper}]/((1 - αLower - αUpper) Sqrt[Length[x]])
(* 0.000680649 *)
```

I think one will need version 11.1 or higher to use the `TrimmedMean` and `WinsorizedVariance` functions.

Comment: (+1) but shouldn't we use [`TrimmedVariance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrimmedVariance.html) instead of [`WinsorizedVariance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WinsorizedVariance.html)?

Comment: @AntonAntonov There you go being logical again.  I'm looking for the article that references using the Winsorized variance....

Comment: I just remembered a discussion on Winsorize here, at MSE: ["Winsorizing in Mathematica and the R package DescTools yields differing results"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/165080/34008).

Comment: @AntonAntonov A reference to the need to use the Winsorized variance rather than the trimmed variance is Tukey JM, McLaughlin DH (1963) Less Vulnerable Confidence and Significance Procedures for Location Based on a Single Sample: Trimming/Winsorization 1. *Sankhya A*, 25:331–352.  A reference to that reference is https://www.medcalc.org/manual/note-trimmedmean.php.

Comment: Good, thanks for providing that reference!